# Monsters would turn into stone/crystals when captured

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I don't remember much, but I know that this cartoon used to air on Cartoon Network and it had monsters which would turn into stones/crystals when defeated. These crystals were then used to summon the monster and fight for the person who had the crystal. (Kind of like Pokémon). Also, the story was going in some world/dimension and the mc's grandpa had something to do with the story too.

Comment: Omg thank you so much

Comment: Same answer, Magi-Nation, as suggested above, but my link was officially accepted by the questioner and since this one seems to be verified by this questioner we can close this as a dupe.